# continuous subform, subtotal in footer

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform for a table order, called orderdetails.

orderDetails has some textboxes that I need to a total from namely, total quantity, total cubic meters and total weight.

quantity and weight are directly inputted by the user (e.g. qty = 10, weight = 22.55) while total cubic meters is a calculation based from user inputs (length * width * height = cbm, sum of each row).

I have named my controls as txtQuantity, txtWeight, txtCBM and their control sources as quantiy, weight, cbm.

I've placed my unbound textboxes at the footer, and placed the formula =sum(txtQuantity) and have gotten #error. I tried =sum(quantity) and also got a #error.

Another side effect is that after placing these controls, I would also get #name for the controls that they are summing(sometimes. I can't pinpoint when, but if I remove the controls in the footer, they all go back to normal).

How can I resolve my totalling problem?

Comment: You need to build a new subform query that groups by your table ID and sums your fields,  then link the subform to your main form using the table ID. All controls in the subform will be set to the summed values in your new query. All I can suggest with the limited info you've provided

Comment: With the subform field in the footer, are you then referring to this field in the mainform? You should be able to `sum()` quantity in the footer as long as the `txtquantity` value is not a string and that `txtquantity` is not a calculated field itself.